# What is the antonym of "inversion" as in "the inversion of normal word order"?

Tags: word-choice

Is there any word for expressing a normal word order, as opposed to an inverted word order?
I prefer the word to be the one mostly used by grammarians.

Comment: I don't know what the specific term is, or if there is one, but *adherence to normal word order* may work.

Comment: Perhaps also consider canonical order, or basic order, or default order, or non-inverted order.

Answer (score 4):

Sentences using the usual word order are termed **unmarked**.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93subject%E2%80%93verb) has:

> ... unmarked sentences (i.e. sentences in which an unusual word order is
>   not used for emphasis) ...

See [sense 2d](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unmarked) given at Dictionary.com. Note that the term is not used solely to identify the usual form of word order; it means lacking *any* sort of emphasis that alternatives might carry.

Comment: +1 There is an intersting discussion of *marked* and *unmarked* [here](http://www.intralinea.org/current/article/marked_and_unmarked_translation_of_english_into_persian). While in the context of translation, it illustrates the means of marking sentences. Inversion is just one form.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can just say the normal word order.

Other possibilities are

- expression
- cliche
- idiom

Answer (score 0):

**Inverse** is one of those interesting words which only seems to exist in the negative. 'Verse' has various meanings but none of them relate to correct order.

The other fascinating thing is that although 'inverse' derives from the Latin *inversus*, the OED has no record of its use prior to the 17th century, which suggests it was not a word brought to us by the Normans.

I am wondering if its use in English owes something to Isaac Newton and the emergence of mathematics in the Enlightenment period.

Comment: *Revert* is sometimes an antonym to *invert*...

Comment: @curiousdannii Umm! But *reverse* is not the antonym of *inverse* is it? In fact are they not synonyms?

Comment: I think that's correct, but when it comes to inversion and reversion they're antonyms again!

Answer (score 0):

When talking about algorithms to invert strings, programmers often use **"Uninverted"** to refer back to the string in its original order.